# ListBox not updating in Windows Phone 7

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have a weird error which I can't figure out.

I am creating a Windows Phone 7 app where I create PivotItems on the fly that contains a ListBox.

Heres the code -

```
        PivotItems = new ObservableCollection<StatusItem>();
        DataTemplate itemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["PivotItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        ListBox itemBox = new ListBox();
        itemBox.ItemsSource = PivotItems;
        itemBox.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate;
        CorePivotItem = new PivotItem() { Header = header, Content = itemBox };
```

Now when I ever I add objects to PivotItems, nothing ever shows up in the UI.

Sorry for not being clear the first time - Here is the DataTemplate binding -

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="PivotItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel >
            <Image Source="{Binding URL}" ></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I am adding the PivotItems to another OC which is binding to a Pivot control. All listings show up fine when I flick across PivotItems. Basically what I am guessing is that the OC is not triggering a refresh on the ListBox. Could I potential use BindingExpressions to force Refresh the list?

Comment: Is your item template definitely okay? If you don't specify it (using the default one) do you get *something* showing up?

Comment: Is this the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114608/databound-pivot-control-is-not-creating-the-first-pivotitem

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show adding the newly create `PivotItem` to the `Pivot`. Is this what you're not doing.

This does of course assume that `CorePivotItem` is not already defined elsewhere.
Can you show your XAML and other C# code so we get the full picture.

Comment: Added more clarity to the question. Thanks for the help guys!