# Databinding PivotItems to ObservableCollection on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I want to databind an ObservableCollection to a Pivot contronl in WP7 so that each object in my ObservableCollection becomes a PivotItem. This is the code I use:

```
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HomeTown}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

This works and with tre items in my ObservableCollection I get three PivotItems. But when everything gets loaded the binding inside the DataTemplate won´t get updated. It is only when I scroll to the next PivotItem that the FirstName, LastName and HomeTown gets loaded.

Why is that? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this discussion:
[DataBound Pivot control is not creating the first PivotItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114608/databound-pivot-control-is-not-creating-the-first-pivotitem)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the workaround with setting SelectedIndex=1 didn't suit me.

I found the other solution: when you adding the Item to your Persons collection you should first create a temp element and only when you fill all data add it to your Persons collection.

```
Person tempPers = new Person() { FullName = "Abduvaliev Edem", FirstName = "Edem", LastName = "Abduvaliev", HomeTown = "Sevastopol"};
Pesrons.Add(tempPers);
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a simple test i cannot reproduce this behavior. I i put a breakpoint inside the get block of the equivalent of FirstName with two items in my ObservableCollection i get two hits.

How did you detect that it is not bound? You cannot see the "next" pivotitems content, so how?

Comment: Hi Jonas. It is the "first" pivotitem's properties that I cannot see. When I slide to the "next" that one show up and so does the "first" when I slide back.

Comment: When do you instansiate the ObservableCollection and when do you add items into it? I my test i created and added the items in the constructor BEFORE setting the DataContext

Comment: But after testing to set the DataContext in the Loaded event it still works for me though

Comment: It shouldn´t matter. But setting MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 1; in the page_loaded solves it. Gotta love the workarounds!

Comment: No that should not matter and it doesn't for me, it still works with both solutions. Setting SelectedIndex will solve it for sure and if you are satisified with that solution, fine :) I think the real problem is within your viewmodel or when you create the items

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's some problem with the loading order - or with the notification code.

Check that you are correctly firing the PropertyChanged event when you set the properties on each of your FirstName, LastName and HomeTown members.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it. The problem for me is that the collection updates asynchronously in response to a web method call.

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _log.Debug("Page loaded.");

    var vm = this.GetViewModel<TrendsViewModel>();

    if (!vm.IsInitialized)
    {
        vm.PivotItems.CollectionChanged += (origin, args) =>
        {
            this.PivotControl.DataContext = null;
            this.PivotControl.DataContext = vm;
        };

        vm.Initialize(this);
    }
}
```

The key is hooking up an observer of the collection to which the Pivot items are bound and giving the data context a shake when it updates.