# DataBinding - How to bind nested properties to the data template?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, pivotitem

I have a data template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyPivotItemTemplate">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding MyClassAName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

in which I've utilized in

```
<controls:Pivot Title="Category" x:Name="myPivot"
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyPivotItemTemplate}">
```

in which I try to pass on a list of ClassA as the pivot item source, which is defined as below

```
Class ClassA
{
    String MyClassAName;
    ...
}
...
ClassA myClassAItem = new ClassA() {MyClassAName = "LOL"};
ClassACollection.Add(myClassAItem);
...
myPivot.ItemSource = ClassACollection;
```

When I try to run the code, the added pivotitem header text is the object name of the collection provided (ie "MyApp.ClassACollection") instead of the value of ClassA's MyClassAName value (ie "LOL"). So how can I bind the each of ClassA item's MyClassAName to each of the dynamically created pivotitem's header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with databinding to a Pivot. See the workaround here:

[DataBound Pivot control is not creating the first PivotItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114608/databound-pivot-control-is-not-creating-the-first-pivotitem)

Also, you header binding path does not match the name property of your class. Try changing to:

```
 <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding MyClassAName}" />
```

Comment: Typo error fixed. The first pivotitem is created correctly, but the problem as stated above remained unsolved.