# WPF combobox with MultiBinding not updating properly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a WPF application that uses a business object like this:

```
public class MyBusinessObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Widget> _myWidgets;
    public ObservableCollection<Widget> MyWidgets
    {
        get { return _myWidgets; }
        set
        {
            if (_myWidgets == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _myWidgets = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyWidgets"));
        }
    }

    private Widget _selectedWidget;
    public Widget SelectedWidget
    {
        get { return _selectedWidget; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedWidget == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedWidget = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedWidget"));
        }
    }

    // more properties here

    public MyBusinessObject()
    {
        Widgets = new ObservableCollection<Widget>();

        // 10 widget objects are instantiated, given names "Widget #1" - "Widget #10" and added to Widgets

        this.SelectedWidget = Widgets.Where(item => item.Name == "Widget #1").FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Each Widget has a .Name property and a .Description property.  The Widget class is defined like this:

```
public class Widget
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Description"));
        }
    }

    public Widget(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = string.Empty;
    }
```

In my UI, I have a combobox that binds to my ObservableCollection of widgets like this:

```
    MyBusinessObject myBusinessObject = new MyBusinessObject();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = myBusinessObject;

        selectedWidgetComboBox.ItemsSource = myBusinessObject.Widgets;
        selectedWidgetComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
    }
```

Here's the XAML for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectedWidgetComboBox" Width="200" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWidget, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="Description" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

As you can see, in my combobox, I'm displaying the widget's name and description together.  When my user has selected a widget from the combobox, I need to allow them to edit the .Description of the widget.  I do that through a small dialog box and then I update the .Description property.  Unfortunately, I'm having a problem getting the combobox to display the new updated description.

When I update the .Description property of the selected widget, the combobox doesn't update as I'd expect it to.  Here's a description of the behavior that I'm seeing:

1. Assume the selected widget has a .Name of "Widget #1".  By default, the .Description property is set to string.empty.  So this appears in my combobox as "Widget #1:".  I then edit the description and set it to "ABC" using this code:

   myBusinessObject.SelectedWidget.Description = "ABC";

When this is done, the combobox still displays "Widget #1:".  If I expand the combobox dropdown and choose another widget (say "Widget #3") and then go back and choose "Widget #1" again, *then* I'll see "Widget #1: ABC" displayed in the combobox.  However, even though the combobox is now displaying "Widget #1: ABC", if I expand the drop-down, I still just see "Widget #1:".  I'm guessing this might be related to the DataTemplate for the ComboBox.ItemTemplate in my XAML but I'm not sure.

Comment: read this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651419/binding-pivot-control-with-observable-collection-mvvm-windows-phone-8/20494475#20494475

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented on Widget, i can't see this interface up there

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh Doh!!!  You're so right.  I completely missed it.  :-(  Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake!